# MySQL error #1064 for NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I encounter this error when creating a table. How can it be fixed?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, mult smallint default NOT NULL, part_des varchar(120) NOT NULL defau' at line 4

```
CREATE TABLE currentpricer_supplier1
(
    supplier_number varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    moq smallint default NOT NULL,
    mult smallint default NOT NULL,
    part_des varchar(120) default NOT NULL,
    uom_qbreak char(2) default NOT NULL,
    costbreak1 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue1 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak2 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue2 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak3 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue3 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak4 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue4 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak5 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue5 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak6 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue6 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak7 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue7 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    costbreak8 smallint default NOT NULL,
    costvalue8 dec(6,3) default NULL,
    leadtime smallint default NOT NULL,
    leadtime_code char(2) default NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (supplier_number)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a default value if you specified a default keyword. "not null" is another specification, not a value itself.

What is the default value? 
e.g.:

> moq smallint default 0 NOT NULL,

Answer (score 1):

On each column with the `default` keyword you haven't supplied a default value. This can be as simple as a `0` for numbers and an empty string for chars after the default. Also, your primary key column doesn't exist, so you need to correct that - is it lumex_number?

The following edit works:

```
CREATE TABLE currentpricer_supplier1
(
    lumex_number varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    moq smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    mult smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    part_des varchar(120) default 0 NOT NULL,
    uom_qbreak char(2) default 0 NOT NULL,
    costbreak1 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue1 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak2 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue2 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak3 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue3 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak4 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue4 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak5 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue5 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak6 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue6 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak7 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue7 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    costbreak8 smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    costvalue8 dec(6,3) default 0 NULL,
    leadtime smallint default 0 NOT NULL,
    leadtime_code char(2) default '' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (lumex_number)
)
```